# OpenLayers overlapping LineStrings issue

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have one set of coordinates from which I create 2 *LineStrings*

```
// global variables, I have previously defined map
let route = null;
let routeFeature = null;
let routeOverlay = null;
let routeOverlayFeatur = null;
```

**My main LineString**

```
function createMainRoute(coordinates) {
   route = new LineString(coordinates);

   routeFeature = new Feature({ geometry: route });

   routeFeature.setStyle(styles.mainRoute);

   const routeLayer = new VectorLayer({
     source: new VectorSource({
        features: [routeFeature],
     }),
   });
   
   map.addLayer(routeLayer);
}
```

**My second LineString with the exact coordinates**

```
function createMainRouteOverlay(coordinates) {
   routeOverlay = new LineString(coordinates);

   routeOverlayFeature = new Feature({ geometry: routeOverlay });

   routeOverlayFeature.setStyle(styles.routeOverlay);

   const routeOverlayLayer = new VectorLayer({
     source: new VectorSource({
        features: [routeOverlayFeature],
     }),
   });
   
   map.addLayer(routeOverlayLayer );
}
```

Now I have a function that draws these 2 lines, this function is called when I get initial data from server

```
function init(coordinates) {
   createMainRoute(coordinates);
   createMainRouteOverlay(coordinates);
}
```

Goal is that I want to modify coordinates on the overlay line like the coordinates, style and so on without loosing track of the main route, but they are at the start the same.

Now I have a function that will dynamically change coordinates set of the overlay line. This function is called when the external data is changed.

```
function readjust(newCoordinates) {
   routeOverlayFeature.getGeomety().setCoordinates(newCoordinates)
}
```

The problem here is that when I call `readjust()`, nothing happens on the map, line stays the same with these new coordinates, but when I comment out `createMainRoute()` from the init function, meaning i only have one line and just call `readjust()`, line is updated with the new data. Does anyone knows what is the issue here? Is something like this not supported or do I need to set some property to allow this? I don't get why they are in conflict when they are 2 separated variables and only one is updated. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your features are sharing the same geometry

```
routeOverlayFeature = new Feature({ geometry: route });
```

should be

```
routeOverlayFeature = new Feature({ geometry: routeOverlay });
```

Comment: I saw it, sry I missed when I was writing the question, in the code everything is ok.

Comment: With that change your functions are working correctly here https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-hugle-dvbb1?file=/main.js

Comment: Thx man, then something  is wrong in my code, just wanted to make sure that it is possible to do it.